# Does The Name Of The Subdomain Affect SEO

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, subdomain, keywords, search

I want to ask if the name of a subdomain can affect search engine optimization (SEO)

I am making a tech website like [cnet.com](https://cnet.com) and also adding a downloads page like [download.cnet.com](https://download.cnet.com) , which will have multiple softwares to download

Now I can name my website ***downloads*.example.com** (with a "s") or ***download*.example.com** (without a "s"), will this affect SEO?

Someone is more likely to serach **"How to download Chrome"** than searching **"downloads"** or **"Browser downloads"** while searching

So will having download.example.com (without a "s") have a better SEO?
Does the words a person search connect/relate to the word in the subdomain?

Comment: See also: [Should I use singular or plural nouns in a domain name and why?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2601/should-i-use-singular-or-plural-nouns-in-a-domain-name-and-why)

Comment: See also: [Do subdomains help/hurt SEO?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/3496/do-subdomains-help-hurt-seo)